# Stability of Electromagnetic Waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-gravity, stability

Is there currently any theory or set of equations which describe the stability of electromagnetic waves in gravity wells of compact objects such as neutron star or a white dwarf star . Weather the 
equilibrium is Stable , Neutral or Unstable?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by stability. If they exist and propagate, until they interact with a charge or a gravitational field they will continue to do so. What equilibrium?

Comment: The equilibrium in which a photon exists in a given position in a massive gravity well . Which can be either stable , neutral or unstable .